# Maximum number of fixed points of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given a finite dimensional vector space over a finite field, what is the linear transformation
$$L : V \rightarrow V $$, which has the most fixed points? ($L$ can not be the identity).

Comment: Consider that the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda = 1$ is the locus of fixed points of the transformation.

Comment: "The" implies there is only one. Also, "most" is weird. The set of fixed points is a subspace of $V,$ so, if the vector space is infinite and finite dimensional, any transformation, if it has any fixed points, has the same number of fixed points.

Comment: All you can really do is classify the transformations that have a maximal subspace of fixed points.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Well, *all* linear transformations from a space to itself have *at least one* fixed point. Some have strictly more.

Comment: @K.Jiang yes, should have added "non-trivial" to my comment

Comment: edited the question, the vector space should be finite.

Answer (score 0):

Any linear transformation that is the identity on a co-dimension 1 subspace, but isn't the identity, will be maximal, no matter which of the possible ways you use to evaluate "most fixed points". And this is of course not unique, so you really can't say "**the** most".

Comment: You can say "the most", you cannot say "the linear transformation", but have to go with "a linear transformation" :)

Comment: Good point. Though possibly one oughtn't use "the" in either place. :)